# R - merge identifiers/rows issues

Tags: r, merge

I have an issue with a simple `merge` and I cannot figure out what is the problem.

I would like to merge two database `dt` and `mt`. Each individual `idno_simple` is observed two times. Like this :

```
  householdid.x idno_simple    idno numchild.x  day_rec   isex
1        101366     1013661 1013661          2 Weekdays FEMALE
2        101366     1013661 1013661          2  Weekend FEMALE
3        101366     1013662 1013662          2 Weekdays   MALE
4        101366     1013662 1013662          2  Weekend   MALE
5        102481     1024811 1024811          0 Weekdays FEMALE
6        102481     1024811 1024811          0  Weekend FEMALE
```

I dont understand why when I merge the two base, suddenly the `idno_simple` are repeatedd 4 times.

```
mdt  = merge(dt, mt, by = 'idno_simple')

 idno_simple householdid.x    idno numchild.x  day_rec   isex hldid_sim persid_sim id_sim nchild_sim day_sim diary_sim sex_sim
1     1013661        101366 1013661          2 Weekdays FEMALE    101366          1      1          2       5         1       2
2     1013661        101366 1013661          2 Weekdays FEMALE    101366          1      2          2       1         2       2
3     1013661        101366 1013661          2  Weekend FEMALE    101366          1      1          2       5         1       2
4     1013661        101366 1013661          2  Weekend FEMALE    101366              1      2          2       1         2       2
5     1013662        101366 1013662          2 Weekdays   MALE    101366              2      1          2       5         1       1
6     1013662        101366 1013662          2 Weekdays   MALE    101366              2      2          2       1         2       1
```

The first database

```
dt = structure(list(householdid.x = c("101366", "101366", "101366", 
"101366", "102481", "102481", "102481", "102481", "103755", "103755", 
"103755", "103755", "103788", "103788", "103788", "103788", "103799", 
"103799", "103799", "103799"), idno_simple = c("1013661", "1013661", 
"1013662", "1013662", "1024811", "1024811", "1024812", "1024812", 
"1037551", "1037551", "1037552", "1037552", "1037881", "1037881", 
"1037882", "1037882", "1037991", "1037991", "1037992", "1037992"
), idno = c(1013661, 1013661, 1013662, 1013662, 1024811, 1024811, 
1024812, 1024812, 1037551, 1037551, 1037552, 1037552, 1037881, 
1037881, 1037882, 1037882, 1037991, 1037991, 1037992, 1037992
), numchild.x = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), day_rec = c("Weekdays", 
 "Weekend", "Weekdays", "Weekend", "Weekdays", "Weekend", "Weekend", 
"Weekdays", "Weekdays", "Weekend", "Weekend", "Weekdays", "Weekend", 
"Weekdays", "Weekdays", "Weekend", "Weekdays", "Weekend", "Weekend", 
"Weekdays"), isex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("FEMALE", 
"MALE"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", .Names =  c("householdid.x", 
"idno_simple", "idno", "numchild.x", "day_rec", "isex"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

The second data

```
mt = structure(list(hldid_sim = c(101366, 101366, 101366, 101366, 
102481, 102481, 102481, 102481, 103755, 103755, 103755, 103755, 
103788, 103788, 103788, 103788, 103799, 103799, 103799, 103799
), persid_sim = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 1, 1, 2, 2), id_sim = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), nchild_sim = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), idno_simple = c("1013661", "1013661", "1013662", 
"1013662", "1024811", "1024811", "1024812", "1024812", "1037551", 
"1037551", "1037552", "1037552", "1037881", "1037881", "1037882", 
"1037882", "1037991", "1037991", "1037992", "1037992"), day_sim = c(5L, 
1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 1L, 
4L, 1L, 4L), diary_sim = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), sex_sim = c(2L, 
  2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("hldid_sim", "persid_sim", "id_sim", 
"nchild_sim", "idno_simple", "day_sim", "diary_sim", "sex_sim"
), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any ideas ?

In my mind the output should respect the 2-rows by individuals structure. I am not sure it is possible.

```
 idno_simple householdid.x    idno numchild.x  day_rec   isex hldid_sim persid_sim id_sim nchild_sim day_sim diary_sim sex_sim
1     1013661        101366 1013661          2 Weekdays FEMALE    101366          1      1          2       5         1       2
2     1013661        101366 1013661          2  Weekend FEMALE    101366          1      2          2       1         2       2
3     1013662        101366 1013662          2 Weekdays   MALE    101366          2      1          2       5         1       1
4     1013662        101366 1013662          2  Weekend   MALE    101366          2      2          2       1         2       1
```

Comment: The first dput is giving me error `Error in structure(list(householdid.x = c("101366", "101366", "101366",  : 
  object 'householdid.x' not found`  Regarding the merge output, it must be related to duplicate entries.  You may need to create a sequence column to make it unique in both dataseta and `merge`.

Comment: Two times two observations makes four combinations, which you get from `merge`. What did you expect?

Comment: @Roland - this is not true because individuals are observed during two days for data 1 and data 2, this is the reason why each `id` has two rows.  So the merging should not add rows but **columns**. It is not two times two.

Comment: @akrun - I fix the data

Comment: Could I just get feedback why the question was downvote ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg - I upload the data again. Let me know if its working now.

Comment: Both the datasets are working fine.  So, what is the expected output

Comment: @akrun - maybe I misunderstand something

Comment: May be `dt$indx <-with(dt, ave(1:nrow(dt), idno_simple, FUN=seq_along)); mt$indx <-with(mt, ave(1:nrow(mt), idno_simple, FUN=seq_along));merge(dt, mt, by = c('idno_simple', 'indx'))`

Comment: @akrun - thanks for the help, i need to look more deeply into the data

Comment: The first 4 rows in your expected output seems to match with the `merge` output and the number of rows is now 20.

Comment: @akrun - yes you can it seems to work. I think I misunderstood the fact that each time there is new variables in different datasets, it will have to add a row.

Comment: The sequence is added based on the `by` variable i.e only for `idno_simple`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `getanID` from `library(splitstackshape)` to create a `.id` column in each dataset based on the duplicate elements in 'idno_simple'.  We join the datasets with the devel version of `data.table`, which also has `on` option so that we don't need to set the `key`.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

```
 library(splitstackshape)
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 getanID(dt, 'idno_simple')[getanID(mt, 'idno_simple'), 
                                   on=c('idno_simple', '.id')]
```

Or a base R option would be using `ave` to create the sequence column and then `merge` as in the comments

```
  dt$indx <-with(dt, ave(1:nrow(dt), idno_simple, FUN=seq_along))
  mt$indx <-with(mt, ave(1:nrow(mt), idno_simple, FUN=seq_along))
  merge(dt, mt, by = c('idno_simple', 'indx'))
```

Comment: I have an error for the first suggestion : `Error in [.tbl_df (data, ,  := (.id, sequence(.N)), by = id.vars) :`

Comment: @giacomoV  The datasets you showed in the example were not `tbl_df`. Have you tried converting it to `data.frame`